# Snake game made in Python

Tags: python, beginner, game, pygame, snake-game

I made a snake game with /some/ code from thenewboston's tutorials when I had just started Python. I think it wasn't a good idea to start game development right away since I didn't even know if what I did was correctly coded.

I didn't use classes and objects since I didn't know how to use them. I'm sure this needs a lot of improving.

**Game.py**

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()


pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 155, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
DARK_CYAN = (123, 104, 238)
YELLOW = (247, 255, 0)

game_title = 'Retro Worm'
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
background_color = BLACK
snake_color = DARK_CYAN
energy_color = DARK_CYAN
polygon_powerup_color = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption(game_title)

global block_size
block_size = 10

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)


def get_collision(p_x, p_y, target_x, target_y, width, height):
    if p_x >= target_x and p_x <= target_x + width:
        if p_y >= target_y and p_y <= target_y + height:
            return True
    return False


def draw_bombs(b_x, b_y, bw, bh):
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [b_x[0], b_y[0], bw, bh])
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [b_x[1], b_y[1], bw, bh])
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [b_x[2], b_y[2], bw, bh])
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [b_x[3], b_y[3], bw, bh])


def set_by_bounds(item_x, item_y, width, height):
    if item_x >= display_height or item_y <= 0:
        item_x = [random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size)]
        item_y = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    return item_x, item_y


def snake(width, height, snakelist):
    for x_and_y in snakelist:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, snake_color, [x_and_y[0], x_and_y[1], width, height])
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, WHITE, [x_and_y[0] + 2, x_and_y[1] + 2, width, height])


def create_bombs(amount):
    bomb_x = list()
    bomb_y = list()
    for am in range(amount):
        bomb_x.append(random.randrange((display_width - block_size) - 30))
        bomb_y.append(30)


def message_to_screen(msg, color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    game_display.blit(screen_text, [200, 300])


def display_score(score):
    screen_text = font.render(score, True, YELLOW)
    game_display.blit(screen_text, [50, 50])


def game_loop():
    pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
    pygame.mixer.music.play(10000)
    fps = 30

    block_size = 10

    running = True
    game_over = False

    lead_x = display_width / 2
    lead_y = display_height / 2
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0

    powerup_x = 0
    powerup_y = 0

    snake_list = list()
    snake_length = 1

    rand_apple_x = round(random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size) / float(block_size)) * block_size + block_size
    rand_apple_y = round(random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size) / float(block_size)) * block_size + block_size

    score = 0
    score_add = 10

    # BOMBS

    # UP BOMBS
    up_bombs_x = [random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                  random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size)]

    up_bombs_y = [0,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0]

    # DOWN BOMBS
    down_bombs_x = [random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                    random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                    random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                    random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size)]

    down_bombs_y = [display_height,
                    display_height,
                    display_height,
                    display_height]

    # LEFT BOMBS
    left_bombs_x = [0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0]

    left_bombs_y = [random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size),
                    random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size),
                    random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size),
                    random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size)]

    # RIGHT BOMBS
    right_bombs_x = [display_width,
                     display_width,
                     display_width,
                     display_width]

    right_bombs_y = [random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size),
                     random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size),
                     random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size),
                     random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size)]

    background_color = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))

    while running:
        while game_over:
            game_display.fill(background_color)
            message_to_screen('Game over. Press R to restart or Q to quit.', DARK_CYAN)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    game_over = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        running = False
                        game_over = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        game_loop()
        # Event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            # Key handling
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    lead_x_change = block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                    block_size += 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    block_size -= 10
        # Map limits
        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
            game_over = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        up_bombs_y[0] += block_size
        up_bombs_y[1] += block_size
        up_bombs_y[2] += block_size
        up_bombs_y[3] += block_size

        left_bombs_x[0] += block_size
        left_bombs_x[1] += block_size
        left_bombs_x[2] += block_size
        left_bombs_x[3] += block_size

        down_bombs_y[0] -= block_size
        down_bombs_y[1] -= block_size
        down_bombs_y[2] -= block_size
        down_bombs_y[3] -= block_size

        right_bombs_x[0] += block_size
        right_bombs_x[1] += block_size
        right_bombs_x[2] += block_size
        right_bombs_x[3] += block_size

        powerup_x += 5
        powerup_y += 5

        # Clean state
        game_display.fill(background_color)
        # Draw
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, energy_color, [rand_apple_x, rand_apple_y, block_size, block_size])
        draw_bombs(up_bombs_x, up_bombs_y, block_size, block_size);

        if 200:
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [left_bombs_x[0], left_bombs_y[0], block_size, block_size])
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [left_bombs_x[1], left_bombs_y[1], block_size, block_size])
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [left_bombs_x[2], left_bombs_y[2], block_size, block_size])
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [left_bombs_x[3], left_bombs_y[3], block_size, block_size])
            if score >= 300:
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [down_bombs_x[0], down_bombs_y[0], block_size, block_size])
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [down_bombs_x[1], down_bombs_y[1], block_size, block_size])
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [down_bombs_x[2], down_bombs_y[2], block_size, block_size])
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [down_bombs_x[3], down_bombs_y[3], block_size, block_size])
                if score >= 500:
                    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [right_bombs_x[0], right_bombs_y[0], block_size, block_size])
                    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [right_bombs_x[1], right_bombs_y[1], block_size, block_size])
                    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [right_bombs_x[2], right_bombs_y[2], block_size, block_size])
                    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, YELLOW, [right_bombs_x[3], right_bombs_y[3], block_size, block_size])

        pygame.draw.circle(game_display, DARK_CYAN, [powerup_x, powerup_x], 10)

        while len(snake_list) > 2:
            del snake_list[0]

        snake_head = list()
        snake_head.append(lead_x)
        snake_head.append(lead_y)
        snake_list.append(snake_head)

        if len(snake_list) > snake_length:
            del snake_list[0]

        snake(block_size, block_size, snake_list)
        display_score('Score: ' + str(score))
        pygame.display.update()

        # --------------- COLLISION -----------------------

        # BOMBS COLLISION
        for index in range(len(up_bombs_x) - 1):
            if get_collision(lead_x, lead_y, up_bombs_x[index], up_bombs_y[index], block_size, block_size):
                game_over = True
        for index in range(len(left_bombs_x) - 1):
            if get_collision(lead_x, lead_y, left_bombs_x[index], left_bombs_y[index], block_size, block_size):
                game_over = True

        # APPLE COLLISION
        if get_collision(rand_apple_x, rand_apple_y, lead_x, lead_y, block_size, block_size):
            rand_apple_x = round(random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size) / block_size) * block_size
            rand_apple_y = round(random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size) / block_size) * block_size
            snake_length += 1
            score += score_add
            display_score(str(score))
            background_color = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
        # POWER-UP COLLISION
        if get_collision(powerup_x, powerup_y, lead_x, lead_y, block_size * 2, block_size * 2):
            score += 50
            powerup_x = 1000
            powerup_y = 1000

        # CHECK IF OUT OF BOUNDS
        if up_bombs_y[0] >= display_height + 200 or up_bombs_y[0] <= 0:
            up_bombs_x = [random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                          random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                          random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                          random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                          random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size)]
            up_bombs_y = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        if left_bombs_x[0] >= display_width + 200 or left_bombs_y[0] <= 0:
            left_bombs_y = [random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size * 2),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size * 2),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size * 2),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size * 2),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size * 2)]
            left_bombs_x = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        if down_bombs_y[0] <= -300:
            down_bombs_x = [random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size),
                            random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size)]
            down_bombs_y = [display_height, display_height, display_height, display_height]
        # ------------------------------------

        # POWER-UP POSITION RANDOMIZATION
        random_spawn_powerup = random.randrange(1000)
        if powerup_x >= display_width or powerup_y >= display_height:
            if random_spawn_powerup == 3:
                powerup_x = 0
                powerup_y = 0
        clock.tick(fps)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

# CODE
game_loop()
```

Comment: See [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/24267/11728) and its answer.

Comment: error: music not loaded

Comment: @inyoot You're probably getting that error because you don't have a `music.mp3` file.

Comment: Yup. I've commented it out. Runs pretty fast. Snake with moving obstacle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, for a beginner, this code is actually quite good! I do have some suggestions for improvement though, specifically regarding documentation and such.

- First off, you did great with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The only errors I'm getting back are that there are too many lines greater than 79 characters long. You do have an unnecessary semicolon on line `233` though.
- You have a lot of code in your `game_loop` function. I would recommend separating this function into smaller functions, each with their own individual purpose. This will help improve readability as well.
- You're missing documentation in your code. The only comments that I see are useless ones like `# DOWN BOMBS`, or `# Event handling`. Comments should be descriptive, and describe a block of code well. For functions, you should use docstrings to describe what they do. Here's an example.

---

```
def my_function(args):
    """
    Flesh this docstring out with useful
    information about the function.
    """
    # Code goes here
```

---

- Another thing that really sticks out here is your naming. The variables you have at the top of the file are mostly all constants. If you have a constant variable (value doesn't change), it's name should be in all uppercase. For example, if a variable has the name `BLOCK_SIZE`, we can tell that it's a constant describing the block size.
- With the issue of naming continued, a few of your variable names are a little hard to understand, for example, from looking at the function argument `b_x`, I don't know what it does. If it's an abbreviation of something, and it's this short, don't abbreviate it.
- My final tip is to format lists, dictionaries, and tuples like the below example. Not in the current form you're doing it. It mostly just improves readability.

---

```
my_list = [
    an_item
    ...
]
```

---

In short, your code is pretty good! I hope that this answer helped you improve your code!

Comment: Great answer! I noticed in some cases that I could use the function ` draw_bombs` more, instead of drawing each rectangle one by one. The variable `b_x` is an array of all the bombs x coordinate. Thanks for the nice answer. :)

Comment: @VicenteBermúdez No problem! :)