# Battle-based snake game in tkinter

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, snake-game

**Disclaimer:** This code is far from complete, I am aware of issues regarding my standards of naming, my lack of comments and readability, however I am encountering a large issue which is preventing me from editing, testing and completing the game. This is not a functional issue, but a performance issue. If you would like a more detailed explanation, this is what I wrote previously on Stack Overflow;

> I am building the following game in tkinter, it's essentially a snake
>   game with two players. Where you would battle the other player until
>   one of you hits the other, the wall or runs out of space. To create the
>   'game' I am using canvases, which are created in a grid. I think this
>   may be the cause of the following issue: When attempting to close the
>   program, python and the script will completely freeze, and take around
>   5-10 seconds to close. I am aware that tkinter may not be the best
>   option for game creation, however this is the way I have chosen and
>   would like to know if there is any way to fix my issue.
>
> To recap: Upon trying to close the following program - the window
>   freezes for around 5-10 seconds. It then closes but obviously testing
>   and actual gameplay is hindered.
>
> One note I would like to make is that the game loads up much quicker
>   than it closes which I find to be strange. Any optimisations that you
>   could recommend would also be welcome however I realise that
>   Stack Exchange is more the platform for this.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import os

velocity = [1,0]
velocity2 = [-1,0]
grid = []
coord = [[10,10]]
coord2 = [[20,20]]
time = 0 
end = False
colour1 = "#d35400"
colour2 = "#9b59b6"
winner = 0
size1 = 0
size2 = 0
loopIds = []
speed1 = 50
speed2 = 50
powers = ["#2ecc71","#e74c3c","#ecf0f1"]
up1 = 0
up2 = 0
down1 = 0
down2 = 0
points1 = 0
points2 = 0

master = Tk()
master.config(bg="#222")
master.title("Trail Snake")
master.wm_state('zoomed')
master.resizable(0, 0)

def start():
    global coord, coord2, colour1, colour2
    for i in coord:
        grid[i[0]][i[1]].config(bg=colour1)
    for i in coord2:
        grid[i[0]][i[1]].config(bg=colour2)

def genPower():
    global h, w, powers
    power = randint(0,2)
    location = [randint(0,h-1), randint(0,h-1)]
    while grid[location[0]][location[1]].cget("bg") != "#222":
        location = [randint(0,h-1), randint(0,h-1)]
    grid[location[0]][location[1]].config(bg=powers[power])

def clear():
    for n in grid:
        for i in n:
            i.config(bg="#222")

def move():
    global coord, coord2, colour1, colour2, size1, size2
    moveSnake(coord, colour1, size1)
    moveSnake(coord2, colour2, size2)

def moveSnake(snake, colour, size):
    global end, h, w, colour1, winner, velocity, velocity2, loopIds, speed1, speed2, powers, up1, up2, down1, down2
    if colour == colour1:
        movement = velocity
        speed = speed1
    else:
        movement = velocity2
        speed = speed2
    if up1 == 0 and down2 == 0:
        speed1 = 50
    if up2 == 0 and down1 == 0:
        speed2 = 50
    if not(snake[0][0]+movement[0] >= 0 and snake[0][0]+movement[0] <= (h-1) and snake[0][1]+movement[1] >= 0 and snake[0][1]+movement[1] <= (w-1)):
        end = True
        if colour == colour1:
            winner = "Purple"
        else:
            winner = "Orange"
    if not end:
        for i in snake:
            grid[i[0]][i[1]].config(bg="#222")
        snake.insert(0, [snake[0][0] + movement[0], snake[0][1] + movement[1]])
        if size == 0:
            chance = randint(1,20)
            if chance == 1:
                size = randint(1,3)
        if size != 0:
            snake.pop()
            path = snake[0]
            size -= 1
        else:
            path = snake.pop()
        for i in snake:
            if grid[i[0]][i[1]].cget("bg") == "#222":
                grid[i[0]][i[1]].config(bg=colour)
            elif grid[i[0]][i[1]].cget("bg") in powers:
                power = powers.index(grid[i[0]][i[1]].cget("bg"))
                if power == 0:
                    if colour == colour1:
                        if up1 == 0:
                            speed1 = 1
                            up1 += 5
                    else:
                        if up2 == 0:
                            speed2 = 1
                            up2 += 5
                elif power == 1:
                    if colour == colour1:
                        if down1 == 0:
                            speed2 = 200
                            down1 += 10
                    else:
                        if down2 == 0:
                            speed1 = 200
                            down2 += 10
                else:
                    clear()
            else:
                end = True
                if colour == colour1:
                    winner = "Purple"
                else:
                    winner = "Orange"
        grid[path[0]][path[1]].config(bg=colour)
        chance = randint(1,100)
        if chance == 1:
            genPower()
        loopId = master.after(speed, lambda snake=snake, colour=colour, size=size: moveSnake(snake, colour, size))
        loopIds.append(loopId)
    else:
        pass # WINNER  

def changeDir(changeDir):
    global velocity
    if velocity[0] == changeDir[1] or velocity[1] == changeDir[0]:
        velocity = changeDir

def changeDir2(changeDir):
    global velocity2
    if velocity2[0] == changeDir[1] or velocity2[1] == changeDir[0]:
        velocity2 = changeDir

def displayGame():
    global h, w
    try:
        main.destroy()

    except: pass

    global wrapper, scoreCount, totalScore, bottom, game

    wrapper = Frame(master, bg="#3498db")
    wrapper.pack(fill=X)

    gameTitle = Label(wrapper ,text="Trail Snake", bg="#3498db", fg="#fff", height=1, pady=10, font=('century gothic',(18)))
    gameTitle.pack(side="top")

    gameWrapper = Frame(bg="#222")
    gameWrapper.pack(expand=True, fill=X, padx=200)

    game = Frame(gameWrapper, bg="#eee", highlightbackground="#2980b9", highlightthickness=5)
    game.pack(side="right")
    game.propagate(0)

    scoresMessage = Label(gameWrapper, anchor="w", fg="#fff", text="Scores this round: (5 games played)", font=('century gothic',(20)), bg="#222")
    scoresMessage.pack(anchor="w")

    playerOneScore = Frame(gameWrapper, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#9b59b6")
    playerOneScore.pack(anchor="w")

    playerScoreIncrease = Label(playerOneScore, text="+1", bg="#8e44ad")
    playerScoreIncrease.pack(side="left")

    WINDOW_WIDTH = master.winfo_screenwidth() / 3
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = master.winfo_screenheight() / 2

    game.config(width=WINDOW_WIDTH, height=WINDOW_HEIGHT)

    SW = game.winfo_screenwidth()
    SH = game.winfo_screenheight()

    h = round(((SH-10) / 15)) - 10
    w = round(((SW-10) / 15))
    w = round(w / 1.8)

    for n in range(0, h):
        grid.append([])
        for i in range(0,w):
            grid[n].append(Canvas(game, bg="#222", height="15", width="15", highlightthickness="0"))
            grid[n][i].grid(row=n, column=i)

    start()
    move()

def restart(event=None):
    global coord, coord2, grid, velocity, velocity2, score, end, loopIds, time, timerId, speed1, speed2, up1, up2, down1, down2

    for n in grid:
        for i in n:
            i.config(bg="#222")
    for i in loopIds:
        master.after_cancel(i)
    loopIds = []
    velocity = [1,0]
    velocity2 = [-1,0]
    coord = [[10,10]]
    coord2 = [[40,50]]
    score = 0 
    end = False
    time = 0
    speed1 = 50
    speed2 = 50
    up1 = 0
    up2 = 0
    down1 = 0
    down2 = 0

    master.after_cancel(timerId)

    start()
    move()

def mainMenu():

    global main

    main = Frame(master, pady=20, padx=20, bg="#333")
    main.pack(expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

    mainLbl = Label(main ,text="Click Start To Begin!", bg="#3498db",anchor="n", fg="#fff", height=1, width=40, pady=20, font=('century gothic',(18)))
    mainLbl.pack(pady=(0,0), fill=X)

    startGame = Button(main, text="Start", command=displayGame, bg="#2ecc71", borderwidth=0, relief=FLAT, height=2, fg="#fff", font=('century gothic',(14)))
    startGame.pack(pady=(10,0), fill=X)

mainMenu()

master.bind("<Up>", lambda Event=None: changeDir2([-1,0]))
master.bind("<Down>", lambda Event=None: changeDir2([1,0]))
master.bind("<Left>", lambda Event=None: changeDir2([0,-1]))
master.bind("<Right>", lambda Event=None: changeDir2([0,1]))

master.bind("<w>", lambda Event=None: changeDir([-1,0]))
master.bind("<s>", lambda Event=None: changeDir([1,0]))
master.bind("<a>", lambda Event=None: changeDir([0,-1]))
master.bind("<d>", lambda Event=None: changeDir([0,1]))
master.bind("<F5>", restart)

master.bind("<F6>", lambda x: master.destroy())
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: So to be clear, everything works correctly, it's just very slow to close?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not explaining properly! I have a couple kinks to work out, like orange snake ALWAYS winning on a head on collision against purple, but the closing is more of a propriety for me.

Comment: Look at some of the points mentioned in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24267/snake-game-using-pygame

Comment: For clarity, you’re closing with f6 and it’s taking long, right? Did you try debugging to see what happens after f6?

Comment: @GürkanÇetin Not sure how I'd check this? [debugging after f6] However, what you've said is correct.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have some, thanks for the read. I'm aware of these points however as I've said above I'd really like to fix the whole freezing issue before making any more modifications! Thanks.

Comment: I use python debugger, and it helps monitoring what’s going on. Elsewhere I’ve read that self.master.destroy() is the way to go, though I never tried any of them.

Comment: Not an expert opinion but using exit() (instead of master.destroy()) immediately kills your program, if that’s what you wanted.

Comment: Still takes some seconds to completely close!

Comment: On my system; the exit command takes zero seconds (and the window immediately closes), while the destroy command takes 3.6 seconds.

Comment: Huh.. really? That's strange. Any ideas?